# Wiremock - Grab a string from the URL, modify it and return it as part of the body

Tags: java, mocking, wiremock

I'm working on some load test scenarios at work and I'm having some issues figuring out how to do this with Wiremock.

It's basically this. I have a piece of code that makes a `GET` to an endpoint that looks something like `/api/1/external/client/1234%12LT` and I want to grab the last part, strip everything after the `%` (included) and only return the numbers before it as part of a very simple JSON `{"id": "1234"}`.

I've been reading about the `Response Templating` and enabled it on my standalone instance by passing the flag `--global-response-templating` on the command line. I *think* it works because if I set it to return a random value using something like `{{randomValue length=10 type='NUMERIC'}}` it actually returns a random number.

I think I should be using a combination of `request.requestLine.pathSegments.[4]` to get the last segment of the URL then use the regular expression extractor `{{regexExtract request.body '[A-Z]+'}}"` (not the actual code, example is taken from documentation) to get the first numerical part but haven't managed to make it work yet.

My mocking code looks something like this:

```
{
  "request": {
    "urlPattern": "/api/1/example/endpoint/.*",
    "method": "GET"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": "200",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "jsonBody": {
      "id": "{{request.requestLine.pathSegments.[4]}}"
    }
  }
}
```

Could anyone point me to where I'm screwing up?.

And another question, how do you debug this usually? I've gone over the docs and not sure how to print info to the logs to see if the substitution I'm trying to do is actually working or if what is reaching the endpoint is what I'm assuming should be getting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you start your WireMock instance with the global reponse templating switched on, then with the following mapping:

```
{
  "request": {
    "urlPattern": "/api/1/external/client/.*",
    "method": "GET"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": "200",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "jsonBody": {
      "id": "{{regexExtract request.requestLine.pathSegments.[4] '[0-9]*'}}"
    }
  }
}
```

Given the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/1/external/client/1234%12LT
```

The response will be:

```
{
    "id": "1234"
}
```

Comment: Looks like I'm having an issue with the helper itself. Getting this on the logs: `wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: inline@712556c0:1:13: could not find helper: 'regexExtract'`. Maybe I'm using an old version or something? I'm trying to find out what's the minimum version that supports that but so far no luck.

Comment: The version I used was [2.25.1](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock-standalone/2.25.1/wiremock-standalone-2.25.1.jar) and the download link to the most recent version can be found in the documentation: [Running as a Standalone Process](http://wiremock.org/docs/running-standalone/).

Comment: Yup, looks like we're using 2.22.something. I'll look into updating it. In the meantime... do you know there's a way to do something similar but just with manipulating strings? I can get the 4th segment in the path correctly so if I could just split it at the % or trim everything after the Nth char would be enough.